# Invasion of the Body Snatchers -- original book: is the nature of the aliens explained?

Tags: alien-invasion, invasion-of-the-body-snatchers

The wikipedia article says that, in Finney's book, the aliens, who live only 5 years, decide to leave Earth in the face of human opposition. This despite the fact that humans have little chance -- not sure what these two apparently contradictory statements mean.

My question is, how would decisions such as this for the alien species be made? In some science fiction with aliens replacing humans, there is the idea that just because an alien has replaced, for example, the president of the US does not mean he is in a position of authority.

In the book, do the aliens have an existence and a consciousness even while still in spore form -- in fact, do they actually live as spores or are the spores just a mechanism of reproduction and the aliens exist, say, in some disembodied form with a "hive mind" or something?

Is the nature of the aliens before assuming human form addressed at all in the book?

Answer (score 4):

I haven't read the book in a while but I did watch the (original) movie, by sheer coincidence, earlier today.  I assume a certain overlap on this scene that would eliminate the concept of a "hive mind".  Miles and Becky walk out of his office after a failed attempt by the pod people to take them over.  They keep blank expressions on their faces and actually converse with a police officer.  I think that if there were a hive mind the officer would have known that he was being fooled.

With regard to the nature of the aliens, it was stated (in the book) by the Manny Kaufman alien that the first attempts at duplication were against some random organic material, some orange juice in an almost empty container, perhaps an axe handle, that kind of thing.  It wasn't until they took over the farmer, (Bernard Budlong?) that they exhibited any cognitive capabilities at all, suggesting that their abilities were limited to those of the host.  As for the pods, pulling up roots as it were, and leaving, most of that, as I recall, was Miles' spin on what he was seeing happen and could simply have been anthropomorphism on his part.  It could simply have been that the pods standard MO was to land on a planet, occupy whatever hosts they could, use them to cultivate more pods to spread elsewhere to continue the cycle.

Some corrections on this post.  I scanned the book last night.  The scene with the police officer is there much as in the movie.  The duplicated matter wasn't orange juice, but a half-empty can of peaches and Budlong wasn't the farmer, but a university professor.

And while there wasn't a borg-style hive mind, the pod people did seem to have a sort of racial memory or perhaps a collective subconscious that made them aware of events before their arrival on Earth.

Comment: Watching movie on Youtube and thought the exact same thing about the police officer. But if the book has them deciding to leave, it seems unclear whether they have cognition or not outside their human form -- unless, as humans, they decide to send spores out knowing that unless they find another intelligent species again, they will remain non-sentient. I will find the book. WHAT'S MORE: they have minds very different from those which they duplicate -- this implies a separate intellect.

Comment: I do like the detail about trying to duplicate orange juice -- it sounds like the author is implying the aliens are motivated by purely chemical "urges" like bacteria. But if their intellect relied solely on what they duplicated, what stopped them from dead ends indeed like orange juice? Something must have realized OJ was not a good idea. Everything points to some kind of intelligence independent of its hosts -- and as I indicated, the dupes have knowledge the humans did not. OJ might be a bad idea because it is inanimate, not because the dupe OJ would not contain sentience. Or something.